# Understanding かなでたり

Tags: words, verbs

I was reading a page (http://kids.goo.ne.jp/shirabemono/detail.html?id=153), but I couldn't understand this phrase:

> 音楽は、音をきいたり**かなでたり**して楽しむものだね。

I understand the "tari form" (or whatever it is called) is being used here, first with 聞く, then with another verb. But I couldn't figure out which verb is かなでたり.

So, which verb is it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reverse conjugating it and looking up something similar in a dictionary?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because (I quote from the site guidance):"we are not willing to provide a translation service for cases where a simple dictionary search combined with understanding the basics of Japanese sentence construction would suffice"

Comment: It's かなでる, to pluck at string instruments.

Comment: Oh, I tried "reverse conjugating" it, but I was doing it the wrong way. I didn't realize that for ichidan verbs it would drop "ru" and add "tari". Sorry it ended up being too simple a question, and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

奏でる, which is the verb “to play” when talking about, among other instruments, the guitar (can also use 弾く、かき鳴らす) and the violin.

You should also note for future reference that the only way a verb can end with an え-row kana and then たり is if たり replaced る.

Comment: 1) Why only guitar and violin? There're more other string instruments, like koto, shamisen, harp, viola, cello, ukulele... And you also use 奏でる for piano, right? 2) Are you saying you do not use 弾く、かき鳴らす for violin?